# Java Regex : How to return the whole word if the words ends with a specific string

Tags: java, regex

Using Pattern/Matcher, I'm trying to find a regex in Java for searching in a text for table names that **end with** _DBF or _REP or _TABLE or _TBL and return the whole table names.

These tables names may contain one or more underscores _ in between the table name.

For example I'd like to retrieve table names like :

```
abc_def_DBF

fff_aaa_aaa_dbf

AAA_REP

123_frfg_244_gegw_TABLE
```

etc

Could someone please propose a regex for this ?

Or would it be easier to read text line by line and use String's method endsWith() instead ?

Many thanks in advance,
GK

Comment: How are you getting this text? Is it coming from some file?

Comment: Use a regex that searches for whatever your word separator is, then any number of letters, then the separator again. For example with a csv look for a comma, then letters, then your ending, and then a comma again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Regex pattern

You could use a simple regex like this:

```
\b(\w+(?:_DBF|_REP|_TABLE|_TBL))\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/dD4lG2/2)**

[image]

### Java code

For java you could use a code like below:

```
String text = "HERE THE TEXT YOU WANT TO PARSE";

String patternStr = "\\b(\\w+(?:_DBF|_REP|_TABLE|_TBL))\\b";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

This is the match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-11]  `abc_def_DBF`
MATCH 2
1.  [28-43] `fff_aaa_aaa_dbf`
MATCH 3
1.  [45-52] `AAA_REP`
MATCH 4
1.  [54-77] `123_frfg_244_gegw_TABLE`
```

### Regex pattern explanation

If you aren't familiar with regex to understand how this pattern works the idea of this regex is:

```
\b          --> use word boundaries to avoid having anything like $%&abc
(\w+        --> table name can contain alphanumeric and underscore characters (\w is a shortcut for [A-Za-z_])
(?:_DBF|_REP|_TABLE|_TBL))   --> must finish with any of these combinations
\b          --> word boundaries again
```

Comment: Many thanks @Fede! This regex seems to work perfect!

Just one additional question please, how could I ignore tables that appear in commented out lines (eg starting with --) ? Would it be easier to parse the text line-by-line and ignore lines starting with -- ?

Comment: @GeorgeK if you have strings in one line you could replace `\b` by anchors having `^(\\w+(?:_DBF|_REP|_TABLE|_TBL))$`. On the other hand, you could do what you said, it is skipping the lines starting with --. If my answer solved your question bear in mind to mark the question as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative might be this regex `".*(_DBF|_REP|_TABLE|_TBL)$"` which means any string that ends in `_DBF` or `_REP` or `_TABLE` or `_TBL`.

PS: Specify the regex to be caseless

Answer (score 0):

This regexp should work to match the whole word:

```
\w+_([Dd][Bb][Ff]|REP|TABLE)
```

Here is is:
[image: word matching]

---

This regexp should work to match the keywords:

```
_(DBF)|(REP)|(TABLE)
```

The `_` is matched, followed by either `DBF` or `REP` or `TABLE`.

It is unclear to me if you wish to match `_dbf` (lower case). If so simply change `DBF` to `[Dd][Bb][Ff]`:

```
_([Dd][Bb][Ff])|(REP)|(TABLE)
```

If you wish to match any more keywords just add another `|(abc)` group.

Of course this method works only if you know that these "keywords" will appear only once, and only at the end of the string. If you have `123_frfg_TABLE_244_gegw_TABLE` for example you will match both.

Below is a screenshot of regexpal in action:

[image: Regexp matching]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("blah".matches(".*[_DBF|_REP|_TABLE|_TBL]$"));
System.out.println("blah_TBL".matches(".*[_DBF|_REP|_TABLE|_TBL]$"));
System.out.println("blah_TBL1".matches(".*[_DBF|_REP|_TABLE|_TBL]$"));
```